# Is sp_send_dbmail with @query param synchronous

Tags: sql-server

Let's imagine that I have a table ExchangeSession with field Processed.

I need to send e-mail with all ExchangeSession with Processed = 0 and then update these sessions to Processed = 1. Like this:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'SomeProfile',
@recipients='SomeAddress',
@subject = 'SomeSubject',
@body = @bodyparam,
@body_format = 'TEXT',
@query = N'SET NOCOUNT ON; select * from ExchangeSession where Processed = 0',
@execute_query_database = @dbnameparam,
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'report.csv',
@query_result_header = 1,
@query_result_width = 32767,
@query_result_separator = @delimiterparam,
@exclude_query_output = 1,
@append_query_error = 0,
@query_no_truncate = 0,
@query_result_no_padding = 1;

update ExchangeSession
set
  Processed = 1
where
  Processed = 0
```

Will sp_send_dbmail executes my query synchronously relatively to the batch or asynchronously? In other words is there any chance that in the e-mail I'll not get all unprocessed sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is YES. query param execution is synchronous relatively to the batch.
Made the following test:

```
insert dbo.[CallLog]([Name]) values ('BeforeMail')

set @queryparam = N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
insert dbo.[CallLog]([Name]) values (''Attachment'');
SELECT
    0 as [ID],
    ...'
...
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    ...   
    @query = @queryparam,
    ...

insert dbo.[CallLog]([Name]) values ('AfterMail')
```

And voila, the results in CallLog:

```
LogID   Name
801 BeforeMail
802 Attachment
803 AfterMail
```

Also I looked at **sysmail_allitems** and **sysmail_mailattachments**. The **send_request_date** value in the **sysmail_allitems** is exactly the same as **last_mod_date** value in the **sysmail_mailattachments**.
And the value of **sent_date** in the **sysmail_allitems** slightly differs.

So sp_send_dbmail executes the query synchronously in the batch, saves results into a file and then later on send an e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain, but I would assume that it is possible that new entries could sneak into your `ExchangeSession` table between sending the email and updating the records. I would play safe by doing:

```
update ExchangeSession
    set Processed = 2   -- This procedure should be the only place that sets Processed to 2
    where Processed = 0

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    ....
    @query = N'SET NOCOUNT ON; select * from ExchangeSession where Processed = 2',
    ....

update ExchangeSession
    set Processed = 1
    where Processed = 2
```

Comment: Dear Skippy, thanks for your reply! But I do not understand how it can help in terms of @query execution context. The question is if sp_send_dbmail executes the query synchronously in the batch and saves the results as attachment and then asynchronously sends an e-mail or if it saves the query as text and then asynchronously executes it.

Comment: I do not care much about new entries as DB is used by only one process. Thanks anyway!